Python errors using QGIS and Google Earth plugin
I'm new to this and I'm trying to use QGIS with the Google Earth Engine and PlanetScope plugins but I got this message,

2024-06-25T15:43:01     CRITICAL    Authentication Manager : Retrieving password from your Keychain failed: Password not found.
2024-06-25T15:46:41     WARNING    Python error : An error has occurred while executing Python code: See message log (Python Error) for more details.

plugin installed and Google Earth Engine verified so any ideas on what the problem is and how do I solve it?
